# Setting a scheduled workflow for every last day of the month

Tags: slack, slack-commands

Is it possible to do it? The options given are not that much specific.

For instance, if the month has only 28 days (Feb), is this my constraint? Every 28th so it can trigger every month?

[Options given](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0LTKU.png)

Didn't try the options above because it will require a month waiting for testing

Answer (score 0):

So far my experience has been that yes, for end-of-the-month workflows the 28th is the constraint, otherwise if you set it to the 30th/31st it will only run when the number matches.

If it's at all possible, I'd recommend moving the workflow to run on the 1st of every month.